# How to preload Vuex store with session information in server-rendered app

Tags: javascript, session, vue.js, vuex, server-side-rendering

When using vue-ssr, you cannot access `localStorage`, so nothing related to the initial state configuration can depend on it. This creates a problem for me, because I was using JWT in localStorage to set the default state of `session` module of my store:

```
export default {
  state: {
    currentUser: !!localStorage.getItem("token"),
  },
  mutations: {
    [AUTH_ATTEMPT](state) {
      state.pending = true;
    },
  }
  // actions and other stuff omitted
}
```

But now that I am trying to server-render my app, how do I refactor this so I can preload the state with currentUser? Note, I am not using Nuxt.

Comment: i think you should use server side session. Even though you are not using Nuxt, [this](https://nuxtjs.org/examples/auth-routes/) should give you some ideas.